# AEM 6.3 Migration - how do I handle configurationFactory in DS annotations?

Tags: migration, osgi, aem, apache-felix, declarative-services

I have a Component that uses SCR annotation with `configurationFactory` set true & I an using a Factory to manage its instances

```
@Reference(
  name = SocialCollaborationServiceFactoryImpl.TRINAING_SERVICE_NAME,
  referenceInterface = SocialCollaboration.class,
  policy = ReferencePolicy.DYNAMIC,
  cardinality = ReferenceCardinality.OPTIONAL_MULTIPLE)
```

This allows multiple instances to be created from the Felix console config manager automatically by clicking a plus sign next to the configuration name and my factory can track it. Now while migrating to AEM 6.3 I am unable to set the configuration factory property to component.This `@Component(property={"conifugrationFactory=true}")` of course does not work.

Any help here to documentation references or suggestions will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using osgi annotations and not felix scr annotations with 6.3, you should be able to use `@Designate(factory=true)`. see [this](https://github.com/apache/sling/blob/4df9ab2d6592422889c71fa13afd453a10a5a626/bundles/extensions/feature-flags/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/featureflags/impl/ConfiguredFeature.java) for a reference implementation.